# Optimal approach to finding "bounding values" in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

### Intended use case

The user defines a start and end date to search for a given error. Errors may be of type "coming" (= occurred at that point in time, indicated by the value `1`) or "going" (= resolved at that point in time, indicated by the value `0`).

To improve the usefulness of the data, it should also be shown when an error had started and when it was resolved *outside the chosen time range*.

There is no minimum or maximum duration of how long an error may have lasted. It may be anything between seconds and weeks.

### Current solution

*The shown data and code are simplified to not make it overly complicated.*

**Data**

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 1 |
| 2022-08-03 | 0 |
| 2022-08-04 | 1 |
| 2022-08-06 | 0 |
| 2022-08-07 | 1 |
| 2022-08-09 | 0 |

**Code**

The current solution consists of three `SELECT`s with two `UNION` statements. First find the last occurrence (independent if it is of value `1` or `0`) before the chosen time range, then find the data within the range, lastly find the first occurrence after the time range.

The code would look like below if the user wants to see errors between 3rd August and 9th August.

```
(
  SELECT DATE, value FROM errors
  WHERE DATE < '2022-08-03'
  ORDER BY DATE DESC
  LIMIT 0,1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT DATE, value FROM errors
  WHERE DATE >= '2022-08-03'
  AND DATE <= '2022-08-09'
  ORDER BY DATE ASC
)
UNION
(
  SELECT DATE, value FROM errors
  WHERE DATE > '2022-08-09'
  ORDER BY DATE ASC
  LIMIT 0,1
)
```

The application code then checks if the values of the first and third queries are even required (i.e. if the first value inside the chosen time range is `1` - error started -, we don't need the `0` value somewhere before the given range).

The actual table contains data for hundreds of different errors (not shown in this example) with several million records. There is already an index in place to optimize the execution time on DATE (and exception code, as mentioned not shown here).

### Optimization possibilities

I wonder how the query might be rewritten to have an optimal query in terms of execution time without changing the underlying data, adding indexes is OK, though. Are there any specific SQL commands available to find these "bounding values" (I copied this term from a Production Historian that has a similar functionality available as part of their API)?

Comment: Do you look at only one error at a time?  (If not, the example may be over-simplified.)

Comment: Yes, it is only one error per request.

Comment: I think the sample data needs to include a second error.  I'm still puzzled on how to also filter on error_num and whether the info is in the same row.  Is the data coming in a simple "error #34 turned ON now" and that is immediately stored as a new row?

Comment: This seems to imply that the middle `UNION` typically delivers 10K rows?  ("millions of rows" / "hundreds of codes")  Are there queries arbitrary date ranges on arbitrary codes?  Or might there be some way to "summarize" the old data each, say, week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have is best optimized by having an index starting with

```
(date, value)
```

(I can't predict how `exception_code` would fit in.)

And make it `UNION ALL`.  (Newer versions have an optimization for `ALL` that does not work for `DISTINCT`.)

"Hundreds of error codes" -- Consider a `SET`, perhaps implemented as several `INTs`, with the errors grouped in some logical way.

Are the rows indicating transitions?  I see not cases of "0" or "1" showing up twice in a row.  This may (or may not) be adding complexity.

I presume your main task is to research the past, not to show the "current" state of each flag?

Based on

```
WHERE exception_code = ... 
  AND date BETWEEN ... AND ... 
ORDER BY date
```

I recommend

```
PRIMARY KEY(exception_code, date)
```

You said "hundreds" of codes, then

```
exception_code SMALLINT UNSIGNED
```

will give you up to 64K codes in only 2 bytes.

I assume the `date` might be a `DATETIME` or even `DATETIME(6)`.  But you might want to avoid daylight savings times hiccups by switching to `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP(6)`.  (The "6" gives you microseconds, but tha takes a little extra space with probably no extra benefit; adjust accordingly.)

Comment: It might be that 0s or 1s might show up multiple times, which might happen if a memory dump of currently active states is written to DB. The `exception_code` would just be another column in the data, also found in the index (which would look like `(exception_code, date)`). The resulting query would be similar to this one: `... WHERE exception_code = ... AND date BETWEEN ... AND ... ORDER BY date`.

Comment: @SaschaM78 - I made some more changes.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the structure of the table, only the query I use. As mentioned in my question, the table structure is different, e.g. the date is stored in Unix time. I'll accept your answer,  as it kind of fits my expectations (that I would need three instead of one query).

Comment: @SaschaM78 - Yes, 3 seems necessary.  You _could_ build another table with a different structure, leaving the existing table alone.  But that may not be worth the effort.  The `UNIONALL` with the index change may be reasonably fast.